# Display Pop up box next to Edit text

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Background** :

1.User click on **Mask** & upload their own image on the mask....

2.Once image uploaded, Edit Text is displaying on image....

3.Once user click on Edit Text, we are displaying pop up box....

**Issue** :

Popup box is displaying at some **random** place....

**Requirement** :

Popup box should display **next** to Edit button....

**How to solve the issue** :

For Pop up box ,  we need to use same positions [left & top] as that of Edit button.... In below code, i included **css** for **Edit** button, but how to use same css for Pop up box ?

**Edit button & pop up code** :

```
if ($(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).length === 1) {
    $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
        "<a onclick='document.getElementById(\"dark\").style.display=\"block\";'><span class=\"edit\" >Edit </span></a>" +
        '<div id=\'dark\' class=\'dark_content\'>content <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"document.getElementById(\'dark\').style.display=\'none\';">Close</a></div> ' +
        "</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).css({
        +
        "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
        "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].height / 2) + "px"
    });
}
```

Please upload images to both mask & test the result....

Codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/yrXEGz

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/gfam1cr0/1/

[video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OvqPNimLnFN1MsvglWjC1kNIdwMa99ak/view)

Code snippet :

```js
var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {  
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,   
      "layers" : [       
        {
          "x" : 160,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,            
              "src" : "ax0HVTs.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "height" : 296,
              "width" : 429,              
              "name" : "L2b-1"
            }            
          ],
          "y" : 291,         
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 25,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,             
              "src" : "hEM2kEP.png",
     "height" : 324,
     "width" : 471,
              "y" : 0,             
              "name" : "L2C-1"
            }
          ],
          "y" :22,         
          "name" : "L2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0, 
      "width" : 612,   
      "name" : "L1"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // below code will upload image onclick mask image

     $('.container').click(function(e) {

        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        console.log(target);
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Below code will fetch mask images from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

            //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ]
            var ImagePosition = arr;
            //code end

            // Display icon only for mask images

            
            //code end

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

                    //  Edit image

if ($(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).length === 1) {
    $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
        "<a onclick='document.getElementById(\"dark\").style.display=\"block\";'><span class=\"edit\" >Edit </span></a>" +
  '<div id=\'dark\' class=\'dark_content\'>content <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"document.getElementById(\'dark\').style.display=\'none\';">Close</a></div> ' +
        "</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).css({
        "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
        "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].height / 2) + "px"
    });
}                
                    // Edit code end here....        
                    
            };
            counter++;
        }       
    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

// jq plugin 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;        

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                initImage = false;
            };
        }

        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            //if (img)
            // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
            // sirpepole  Add this
            return settings.id;
        };


        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        // code end
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
 background: gold;
 position: relative;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.txtContainer {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF
}

.txtContainer:hover {
 background: red;
 padding: 1px;
 border-style: dotted;
}

.pip {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.edit {
 display: block;
 background: #444;
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
}

.edit:hover {
 background: white;
 color: black;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
}

.dark_content {
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 top: 25%;
 left: 25%;
 width: 350px;
 height: 350px;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 16px solid orange;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1002;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just update your code with few **script** changes. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {  
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,   
      "layers" : [       
        {
          "x" : 160,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,            
              "src" : "ax0HVTs.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "height" : 296,
              "width" : 429,              
              "name" : "L2b-1"
            }            
          ],
          "y" : 291,         
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 25,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,             
              "src" : "hEM2kEP.png",
     "height" : 324,
     "width" : 471,
              "y" : 0,             
              "name" : "L2C-1"
            }
          ],
          "y" :22,         
          "name" : "L2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0, 
      "width" : 612,   
      "name" : "L1"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // below code will upload image onclick mask image

     $('.container').click(function(e) {

        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        console.log(target);
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Below code will fetch mask images from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

            //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ]
            var ImagePosition = arr;
            //code end

            // Display icon only for mask images

            
            //code end

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

                    //  Edit image

if ($(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).length === 1) {
    $("<span class=\"pip pip" + newImageLoadedId + "\">" +
        "<a onclick='document.getElementById(\"dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\").style.display=\"block\";'><span class=\"edit edit" + newImageLoadedId + "\" >Edit </span></a>" +
    "</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).css({
        "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
        "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].height / 2) + "px"
    });
    $("<div id=\'dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\' class=\'dark_content\'>content" +
      "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"document.getElementById(\'dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\').style.display=\'none\'\">Close</a>" + "</div>").appendTo(".pip" + newImageLoadedId).css({
      "left": $('.edit' + newImageLoadedId).width() + 2 + "px",
      "top": "0px"
    });
}                
                    // Edit code end here....        
                    
            };
            counter++;
        }       
    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

// jq plugin 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;        

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                initImage = false;
            };
        }

        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            //if (img)
            // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
            // sirpepole  Add this
            return settings.id;
        };


        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        // code end
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
 background: gold;
 position: relative;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.txtContainer {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF
}

.txtContainer:hover {
 background: red;
 padding: 1px;
 border-style: dotted;
}

.pip {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.edit {
 display: block;
 background: #444;
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
}

.edit:hover {
 background: white;
 color: black;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
}

.dark_content {
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 top: 25%;
 left: 25%;
 width: 350px;
 height: 350px;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 16px solid orange;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1002;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```